# What is the cleanest way to abort a construction of a new object in c#, and instead return a reference to an object that already exists?

Tags: c#, object, constructor, reference, instance

I would like for a constructor to somehow abort the construction of a new object, and instead return a reference to an object that already exists. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: That's impossible to do from a constructor - you'd need to use helper function which either constructs a new object or returns a reference to an existing one

Comment: I smell an X-Y problem.

Comment: The alternative to factories is some form of object pooling where the publicly constructible object is a lightweight wrapper that borrows the "heavy" objects from a private pool.

Comment: The factory pattern is what you need. For example: it will calls the constructor of the desired type from where can be thrown an exception catched by the factory that returns another existing object, else the constructed if success. This will be designed to disallow the creation of the instance directly but only from the factory.

Comment: `new` _almost always_ means a new object is created. Factory pattern is likely your best bet, or some kind of cache / dictionary.

Comment: [Factory Method Design Pattern In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which is clean and makes it clear for users of the class.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support this sort of thing. You are best served using the factory pattern to transparently perform this work.